# Java: Reverse sorting methods

Tags: java, quicksort, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

So these sorting methods sort numbers in a lesser to greater order, how would I reverse these? I've tried reversing the operations but that doesn't seem to work :/

Still trying to learn Java, thank you for the help

```
//Selection Sort Method
public static void SelectionSort(int a[], int n) {
    int smallest;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        smallest = i;
        //see if there is a smaller number further in the array
        for (int index = i + 1; index < a.length; index++) {
            if (a[index] < a[smallest]) {
                swap(a, smallest, index);
            }
        }
    }
}

//Selection Sort swap method to call on
public static void swap(int array2[], int first, int second) {
    int hold = array2[first];
    array2[first] = array2[second];
    array2[second] = hold;
}

//Bubble Sort Method
public static void BubbleSort(int a[], int n) {
    int i, j, t = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (a[j - 1] > a[j]) {
                t = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = t;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Insertion Sort Method
public static void InsertionSort(int a[], int n) {
    int insert;
    for (int next = 1; next < a.length; next++) {
        insert = a[next];
        int moveItem = next;
        while (moveItem > 0 && a[moveItem - 1] > insert) {
            a[moveItem] = a[moveItem - 1];
            moveItem--;
        }
        a[moveItem] = insert;
    }
}

//Quick Sort Method
public static void QuickSort(int a[], int low, int high) {
    int partitionLoc;
    if (low < high) {
        partitionLoc = partition(a, low, high);
        QuickSort(a, low, partitionLoc - 1);
        QuickSort(a, partitionLoc + 1, high);
    }
}

public static int partition(int a2[], int left, int right) {
    boolean moveLeft = true;
    int separator = a2[left];

    while (left < right) {
        if (moveLeft == true) {
            while ((a2[right] >= separator) && (left < right)) {
                right--;
            }
            a2[left] = a2[right];
            moveLeft = false;
        } else {
            while ((a2[left] <= separator) && (left < right)) {
                left++;
            }
            a2[right] = a2[left];
            moveLeft = true;
        }
    }
    a2[left] = separator;
    return left;
}
```

Comment: Reversing the comparison should do the trick. In BubbleSort, for example change `if (a[j - 1] > a[j])` for `if (a[j - 1] < a[j])`.

Comment: You would have to reverse _all the logic_.  For example, in selection sort you'd need to keep track of the largest number in addition to reversing the comparison.

Comment: Why don't you use "Arrays.sort(data, Collections.reverseOrder());"

Comment: something so simple but yet i couldn't see it haha, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Kartic I'm using a list of randomly created numbers with a size inputted by the user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave your method as is and reverse the array:

```
public static void reverse(int[] a) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < a.length / 2 ; i++) {
        int t = a[i];
        a[i] = a[a.length - 1 - i];
        a[a.length - 1 - i] = t;
    }
}

int[] a = // ...
whateverSort(a);
reverse(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reverse the comparison in each sort:

- SelectionSort

  ```
  a[index] < a[smallest] => a[index] > a[smallest]
  ```
- BubbleSort

  ```
  a[j - 1] > a[j] => a[j - 1] < a[j]
  ```
- InsertionSort

  ```
  a[moveItem - 1] > insert => a[moveItem - 1] < insert
  ```
- QuickSort

  ```
  (a2[right] >= separator) => (a2[right] <= separator) 
  (a2[left] <= separator) => (a2[left] >= separator)
  ```